# What's wrong with my try catch block? (File i/o)

Tags: java, file-io

The error that I get is "try" without a catch block. The file i/o is part of a tree that I'm making.

```
public static void main(String args[])
      {
        LinkedBSTree l = new LinkedBSTree();
        String fileName = "file.txt";

        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fruitFile))){

          String line;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] item = line.split(" ");
            l.insert(item[0], Float.parseFloat(item[1]));
          }
        } catch(IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        l.printInOrder();
      }
```

Comment: Which java compiler are you using? The try (...) is a recent feature.

Comment: JDK 6.0_65 is my compiler

Comment: I believe the try with resources was introduced in java 7: (edited with a more official source) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html

Comment: @alan thank you! i'll check it out

Comment: Java 6 is way out of date.  Java 7 out of date too.  Both products are beyond end-of-life.  Unless you have a Java support contract with Oracle, you should upgrade your systems to use a Java tool chain that is still receiving (free) security patches.  Java 8 ... soon Java 9.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you are trying to use a Java 7 language feature with a Java 6 compiler.  The  Java 7 (and later) "try-with-resources" syntax is not recognized by your compiler and that leads to compilation errors:

Solution: upgrade your toolchain to the *latest* Java release.  (Don't upgrade to Java 7 unless you have a support contract.  That toolchain is beyond end-of-life as well.)

Answer (score 0):

The try-with-resources: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html is a new feature of Java 7. You cannot use it in JDK 6.

In JDK 6, you can only try-catch:

```
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    LinkedBSTree l = new LinkedBSTree();
    String fileName = "file.txt";

    try{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fruitFile));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] item = line.split(" ");
            l.insert(item[0], Float.parseFloat(item[1]));
        }
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    l.printInOrder();
}
```

Hope this could help you.